# How do I prevent my output from dropping below zero?

Tags: java

I am trying calculate the difference between apartment prices but I can't let the price become negative/fall below zero. I want to print both prices. As of right now my output is correct with the test code except that one is negative. How do I prevent my output from dropping below zero?

```
public class Apartment {

private int rooms;
private int squareMeters;
private int pricePerSquareMeter;


public Apartment(int rooms, int squareMeters, int pricePerSquareMeter) {
    this.rooms = rooms;
    this.squareMeters = squareMeters;
    this.pricePerSquareMeter = pricePerSquareMeter;

}

public boolean larger(Apartment otherApartment){

    if(this.squareMeters > otherApartment.squareMeters){
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public int price(){

return squareMeters * pricePerSquareMeter;
}

public int priceDifference(Apartment otherApartment){


return this.price() - otherApartment.price();

}

}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write testcode here
    Apartment studioManhattan = new Apartment(1, 16, 5500);
    Apartment twoRoomsBrooklyn = new Apartment(2, 38, 4200);
    Apartment fourAndKitchenBronx = new Apartment(3, 78, 2500);


System.out.println( studioManhattan.priceDifference(twoRoomsBrooklyn) );        // 71600
System.out.println( fourAndKitchenBronx.priceDifference(twoRoomsBrooklyn) );    // 35400

}
}
```

Comment: if(output<0) output=0;

Comment: Thank-you. Sorry I forgot to mention I was trying to not use an if statement other wise I would have. I used Eran's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the absolute difference, use Math.abs :

```
public int priceDifference(Apartment otherApartment)
{       
    return Math.abs(this.price() - otherApartment.price());    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eran. I completley spaced on using Math.

Comment: High School arithmetic is actually useful sometimes!